# unable to place submit button inside input in bootstrap 4.3.1

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Am working bootstrap 4.3.1 and i am trying to place submit button inside input and tried below method and more form stackoverflow.

since my input is `rounded-pill` i need to place button inside input filed.

How can i place button inside input field

```css
@import url("https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

```html
<div class="input-group col-md-4">
  <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-pill" id="x__p__address__x" size="70" style="font-size:small" />
  <span class="input-group-append">
            
              <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary rounded-circle">go</button>
            </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute to absolutely position the button inside the input field. Also add the z-index property to ensure it stays at top of input when you focus the input field.

```css
@import url("https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css");
body {
  margin: 20px;
}

.input-group {
  position: relative;
}

.form-control {
  padding-right: 47px;
}

.input-group-append {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group col-md-4">
  <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-pill" id="x__p__address__x" size="70" style="font-size:small" />
  <span class="input-group-append">
      <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary rounded-circle py-1">go</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any way to align button perfectly inside input field

Comment: Added a py-1 class on button. Does this help ?

Comment: yes it helped with little change, removed text`Go` and `fonticon`

Answer (score 1):

add this

```css
.input-group-append {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
.x__p__address__x {
    padding-right: 40px;
}
```